# What design pattern to use in serial communication on different platform?

Tags: design-patterns, cross-platform

I want to implement a serial communication class which can be used both on linux and windows platform. Is factory method suitable for this class? How to deal with header files on different platform?for example I want to compile the code on windows so I can't use the header files on linux, Should I use the pre-processor instead?

```
  //pseudocode

    class ComDevice
    {
    virtual void getBytes()=0;
    };
    class LinuxComDevice:public ComDevice
    {
    void getBytes();
    };
    class WindowsComDevice:public ComDevice
    {
    void getBytes();
    };

    class DeviceFactory
    {
    ComDevice createDevice()
    {
        if(platformIsWindows())
            return new WindowsComDevice();
        else return new LinuxComDevice();
    };
    };
```

Comment: What language are you coding this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Factory. However Factory would be a little overkill if you are only going to have Windows/Linux. If you anticipate that you would be asked to support lot many platforms in the future then makes sense to do what you have done.

> How to deal with header files on
>   different platform?

Didn't quite understand this part. What do you want to compile?